# How can I test exceptions using Test Driven Design concept in eclipse

Tags: java, exception, junit, testdrivendesign

I'm writing a Stack class using the Test Driven Design concept.

In the setUp() method my stack is created with 0 elements like this

```
Stack stack = new Stack();
```

This is my attempted test to catch the StackEmptyException which would be raised when top is immediately called after setUp().

```
@Test
public final void testTopIsEmpty() throws StackEmptyException
{
  StackEmptyException thrown = null;
  try
  {
    stack.top();
  }
  catch (StackEmptyException caught)
  {
    thrown = caught;
  }
  assertThat(thrown, is(instanceOf(StackEmptyException.class)));
}
```

My problem is in the last line. I don't understand why my code doesn't work!

Answer (score 3):

ExpectedException can be used to verify that an exception is thrown. The check can be in the middle of a method to make sure earlier method calls don't accidentally throw the same exception.

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testTopIsEmpty() throws StackEmptyException {
    thrown.expect(StackEmptyException.class);
    stack.top();
}
```

Comment: EE also allows for checking the exception message (in case the method under test is capable of throwing an exception in multiple situations)

Comment: +1 for newer (and better!) JUnit stuff like Rule on ExpectedException. It allows for much clearer code.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to [test for an exception](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Test.html#expected%28%29) in JUnit is:

```
@Test(expected = StackEmptyException.class)
public final void testTopIsEmpty() throws Exception
{
    stack.top();
}
```

Comment: I dislike this method of testing for exceptions because in a larger test (with more than one statement), the test merely states if an exception has occurred. With my logic, I can use the throw/catch block to explicitly learn if and from where the exception has been raised. Please understand while I wait for another answer.

Comment: Ok, try using `assertTrue(thrown instanceOf StackEmptyException.class)` and change the type of thrown to just `Exception`. What happens when you run it?

Comment: @DannyRancher You probably shouldn't have those larger tests to begin with. Maybe you could ask a new question asking how to test for your specific use case?

Comment: One of ways. Not the only one, not the best IMO. I much prefer the `@Rule public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();` way. For why - Szczepan, Mockito creator, put it greatly in words [in his blog posts](http://monkeyisland.pl/2010/07/26/expected-exception-in-tests/)